# Как сделать чтоб когда бота добавляли в группу он что то писал по типу Успешно добавлен в группу aiogram 3?

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram, бот, aiogram-3.x

Мне нужно сделать что когда бота добаляют группу он писать "Бот успешно добавлен" на aiogram 3

Comment: Делайте. Мы не возражаем

Comment: Мне нужен пример как можно сделать события добавления бота в группу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример хендлера:

```
@router.my_chat_member(ChatMemberUpdatedFilter(member_status_changed=JOIN_TRANSITION))
async def bot_added(event: ChatMemberUpdated, bot: Bot):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=id, text=f"Бот добавлен в {event.chat.title}, username: {event.chat.username}")
    # делаем что-нибудь еще
```

Бот будет в указанный чат: Бот добавлен в "Название группы/канала", username: "юзернэйм канала, если есть"

Comment: Больщое спасибо